# struts2 - How to get username on every page in my web application

Tags: java, struts2

I have used interceptors to check if the user is valid & if so send him to the action otherwise deny him from doing the action.I have added it into the default-stack so that it can occur on every action the user is invoking.
Its working fine & I am getting the desired results, the only issue is that now I want to show the username on the header of every page. So is there a way I can send some variable like username from the interceptor to every action I am invoking or directly to the jsp?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I got my answer. I just need to implement session aware and use the session object where ever needed.

Comment: That isn't a very good way.  Your actions don't need session aware, the session map is directly accessible from the JSP (it's on the value stack already). If the site is small you can get away with writing directly into each jsp, but cut and pasting should make you think there is a better way... the better way is sitemesh and tiles2.

Comment: I read what you wrote as using session aware on every action for which you wanted to display the user name, where you probably only used it on the login action... so never mind that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to persist it in a way each request can access the authenticated object. The way is to store the user object in session or at least store an identifier like username with which you could retrieve the user object again.

Comment: To display the username on each page, simply use the property tag.
<property value="#session.username" />

Answer (score 1):

you can add the data into the session & access the session value in every page...

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what library you are using. but i think the generic way to retrieve the current user's username is by invoking httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName()

it also works when i use spring security

Answer (score 0):

Another option.  In your base action add:

```
public String getLoggedInUser() {
  return ServletActionContext.getRequest().getRemoteUser();
}
```

And within your (jsp) views you will be able to access the currently logged in username via:

```
${loggedInUser}
```

or

```
<s:property value="loggedInUser"/>
```